# What is a trace function, with regards to Hooke's Law?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading through a paper on modelling stress and strain, and I came across this equation for Hooke's Law, representing the two as $3\times3$ matrices:

$$\sigma= 2\mu \epsilon + \lambda \text{Trace} (\epsilon) * I$$

Strain here refers to Green's symmetric strain tensor:

$$\epsilon = J_{u}(p)J_{u}^{t}(p) - I$$

The paper tells me that the two constants are the Lamé constants for the material, which is fine, and I think I is an identity matrix, but I have no idea what the $\text{Trace}(\ldots)$ function is about. Any ideas?

Comment: If I recall $\varepsilon$ is a stress tensor of sorts correct?

Comment: Yes, should probably have added that to the question, the paper uses Green's strain tensor $\epsilon = J_{u}(p)J_{u}^{t}(p) - I$

Comment: Are you just asking what the trace of a matrix is (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)), or are you asking why it appears here?

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for @NateEldredge, cheers! My initial search didn't pick up that page, I feel pretty silly now